# Cartersian Product like operator consisting of sets/unordered pairs rather than ordered pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given sets $A$ and $B$, I want to obtain a set $C$ that contains all possible sets containing exactly one element from $A$ and one element from $B$.

For example, suppose $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,3\}$, $C= \{ \{1\}, \{1,3\},\{2,1\},\{2,3\}\}$.

The only difference here is that the elements of $C$ are sets rather than pairs.

Is there already any defined operator that perform this ?

Comment: If you are talking about "cartesian product" in your example you can't take the single element $\{ 1 \} \in C$ but instead you should take $\{1,1\}$.

Comment: @Gabrielek $\{1,1\}=\{1\}$, Noor's pairs aren't ordered

Comment: As for the question I'd just write $C=\{\{a,b\}\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$, there's no specific notation or name for it as far as I'm aware

Comment: So with this notation he has just described the usual cartesian product $A \times B$

Comment: No, in the cartesian product you have ordered pairs, here Noor is taking a "cartesian product but with unordered pairs"

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti. I'll do this, I was confirming before, thanks

Comment: I edited the title for better clarity.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there is no commonly used notation for an operation such as that.

You could however write
$$
C = \lbrace \lbrace a, b \rbrace \mid a \in A \text{ and } b \in B \rbrace ,
$$ 
or, equivalently
$$
C = \lbrace \lbrace a, b \rbrace \mid (a, b) \in A \times B \rbrace .
$$